# check if any of the input inside the form is empty

Tags: javascript, jquery

What I'm trying to do is check if any of the inputs that have the required property are empty.
If they do then alert "empty" but it only detects the first input. Any ideas, help?

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
        if(!$("form input[required]").val()){
            alert("empty");
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="" method="">
    <div>
        <input type="text" required/>
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="text" required/>
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="text" required/>
    </div>
</form>
<button>test</button>
```

Comment: check my answer it will get placeholder text. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$("form input[required]").val()` will return only the value of first input with `required` attribute.

You need to iterate over each of the required input element and check whether it has a value - probably by trimming(as done below) to exclude blank values.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("button").click(function() {
    var $empty = $("form input[required]").filter(function() {
        return !this.value.trim();
      }),
      valid = $empty.length == 0,
      items = $empty.map(function() {
        return this.placeholder
      }).get();

    if (!valid) {
      alert("below itema are empty: \n" + items.join('\n'));
    }

  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="" method="">
  <div>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Item A" required/>
  </div>
  <div>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Item B" required/>
  </div>
  <div>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Item C" required/>
  </div>
</form>
<button>test</button>
```

Comment: I want to get the placeholder of the empty fields that has a required property (assume that I have put placeholder on each input), any ideas, help?

Comment: @CodeDemon what do you want to do with that

Comment: I want to create a custom error notification where all the unfilled required inputs fields placeholder will be listed so that user could know what fields have error.

Answer (score 1):

Use like this:

```
if($("form input[required]")).filter(function(){
   return $(this).val().length === 0;
  }).each(function(){
      alert("empty");
  });
```

Comment: What is the result of `$("form input[required]")` ?

Comment: That will just check if the input is required.

Comment: Although, your line of thinking is right, the `.length` part will only give you the length of the value of number of elements that are `required` :)

Answer (score 1):

You will have to loop through all the elements in this case.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("button").click(function(){
     var isEmpty = false;
     $("form input[required]").each(function(){
        if(!$(this).val()){
           isEmpty = true;
        }
     });
     if(isEmpty) alert('Empty');
  });
});
```

Comment: What is second textfiled is empty and third is not ?

Comment: Good question, in that case, the `isEmpty` is still `true` because the `if` condition will fail for 3rd input. :) Hence, ALERTTTT! :D

Comment: Correct! But don't you think breaking the iteration is better option coz there are 100 textfields and first one is empty..

Comment: Good point. However, usually, the validations are run to point out what all inputs are invalid. So that we can appropriately `addClass`. :) It is not mentioned here so it would make more sense to just break it off. Depends on the requirement though. :)

Answer (score 1):

You will need to loop over all found element to check if at least one of them is not filled in. It's convenient to use [Array.prototype.some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) method here:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("button").click(function(){
    
    var hasEmpty = $("form input[required]").toArray().some(function(el) {
      return !el.value.trim();
    });
    
    if (hasEmpty) {
      alert("empty");
    }
    
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="" method="">
  <div>
    <input type="text" required/>
  </div>
  <div>
    <input type="text" required/>
  </div>
  <div>
    <input type="text" required/>
  </div>
</form>
<button>test</button>
```

Comment: Thank you for providing your approach. I am always fascinated by these seemingly `complicaed` syntaxes and see myself thinking in this way in near future. :) Although it seems more complicated for the current problem, it sure does come handy while doing some unusual dom manipulations in certain scenarios. :) Thank you again.

Comment: Complicated? I would say this is the most logical and straightforward approach. Plus probably the most efficient and concise and at the same time readable. ES provides this method `some` exactly for this purpose - test if some of the elements of the array passes the test and return immediately, so it doesn't keep checking if passing element found.

Comment: Pardon my choice of words. By complicated I mean `neatly` chaining the function calls and achieving results in `one line`. :) Yes, this is the best solution and pretty straightforward. To the non-seasoned eye, it `appears` to be `complicated`. :D

Answer (score 1):

You just need to use this in `.each` method so that you can select every required element . Just like this [Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ytLxmaxd/1/)

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("button").click(function(){
 $("form input[required]").each(function(){
        if(!$(this).val()){
           alert($(this).attr('name')+" is empty");
        }
     });
  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="" method="">
  <div>
    <input name="input1" type="text" required/>
  </div>
  <div>
    <input name="input2" type="text" required/>
  </div>
  <div>
    <input name="input3" type="text" required/>
  </div>
</form>
<button>test</button>
```

**Update**

after reading comment if you want to get placeholder text [Check this](http://jsfiddle.net/ytLxmaxd/2/) . You can use `$(this).attr('placeholder')`

Answer (score 1):

please try this for form submit.

```
 $("form").submit(function(){

  $("form input[required]").each(function(){
    if(!$(this).val()){
       alert($(this).attr('name')+" is empty")

 });
```

your html look like this.

```
<form action="" method="">
 <div>
 <input type="text" required/>
 </div>
  <div>
  <input type="text" required/>
  </div>
  <div>
  <input type="text" required/>
  <input type="submit" value="test"/>
  </div>
  </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need tou use each function to get value of 'input required'

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){

        $("form input[required]").each(function(e,ui){
            if(!$(ui).val()){
               alert(e,' - empty');
            }
        });

    });
});
```

Comment: Please add a description of what you did and why this is working, tx